# Inkscape - Path - Difference - Preserve Color

Tags: color, path

I am new to Inkscape and I am trying to create a "pupil" in an "eye".

I have a yellow circle with a white circle for an eye. I create a black circle over the eye where I want the pupil to be, and then to conform the black circle within the eye I am using "path" and "difference". This works as I want in terms of the placement of the new "pupil" area, although my "pupil" is made to be yellow, I would like to make it black, as is the color of the circle I used in the first place. I hope that makes sense.

Here are some pictures of what I mean.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible the way you are trying to do it. If you merge the white circle with the black by using Difference, it will be one object, and one object can only have one fill.

I think what you probably want to do is make sure the white circles are cut out off the yellow circle - use Difference to do that. Then you can draw the black circle and send it to the back of the stack, using Object > Lower to Bottom. Then the black pupils will show through the holes you cut.

[image]

[Here's the Inkscape SVG](http://www.filedropper.com/drawing_4) if you want to examine it.

Note: the black stroke around the yellow circle is in fact a separate copy of the circle, with a black stroke and no fill applied.

Another way to do this is to draw the white filled circle then the black filled pupil, then you could use Path > Division, which would give you two cut objects you could then apply separate fills to.

[image]